# jQuery validate URL but still pass validation if it's not required

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the following code to validate each sections inputs as I'm creating a full page form and need to validate on click before you can move to the next section this is my code:

```
function isSectionValid(){
    var $section = $('.section.active').find('input');
    var allValid = true;
    if($section.valid()){
        return allValid;
    };
};
```

it works fine in my if statement for

```
if(isSectionValid()){
    scrollPage(next, null, false);
    setTimeout(hideUp, 200);
    setTimeout(hideBottom, 200);
    animForm();
}
```

Validation Code:

```
$(function() {
    //Add Error divs
    function addErrordivs() {
        var $inputs = $('input');
        $inputs.each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            $(this).before('<div id="' + name + 'error"></div>');
        });
    };
    window.onload = addErrordivs();
    //Validate form
    $("#ampform").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            //Custom error placement
            var name = $(element).attr('name');
            var errorname = 'div#' + name + 'error';
            $(errorname).html(error);
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            window.location = "http://meow.com";
        },
        rules: {
            "site": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            "personalsiteurl": {
                required: false,
                url: true
            },
            "blogurl": {
                required: false,
                url: true
            },
            "name": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            "email": {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            "password": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },
            "headerimage": {
                required: true
            },
            "header1": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            "header2": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            "headerfont": {
                required: true
            },
            "menucolor": {
                required: true
            },
            "menufontcolor": {
                required: true
            },
            "menufont": {
                required: true
            },
            "backgroundcolor": {
                required: true
            },
            "sitefontcolor": {
                required: true
            },
            "sitefont": {
                required: true
            },
            "galleryimages": {
                required: true
            },
        },
        messages: {
            "site": {
                required: "Please enter your new AMP ⚡ website's name ",
                minlength: "Your new AMP ⚡ website's name must be at least 5 characters long "
            },
            "personalsiteurl": {
                required: "Please enter your personal website's name if you have one "
            },
            "blogurl": {
                required: "Please enter your blog's name if you have one "
            },
            "name": {
                required: "Please enter your Name ",
                minlength : "Your name must be at least 2 characters long "
            },
            "email": {
                required: "Please enter your email address "
            },
            "password": {
                required: "Please enter a strong password ",
                minlength: "Password must be at least 10 characters "

            },
            "headerimage":{
                required: "Please upload your header image "
            },
            "header1":{
                required: "Please choose your primary header ",
                minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters "
            },
            "header2":{
                required: "Please choose your secondary header ",
                minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters "
            },
            "headerfont":{
                required: "Please choose a header font "
            },
            "menucolor":{
                required: "Please choose your menu background color "
            },
            "menufontcolor":{
                required: "Please choose your menu font color "
            },
            "menufont":{
                required: "Please choose your menu font "
            },
            "backgroundcolor":{
                required: "Please choose your website background color "
            },
            "sitefontcolor":{
                required: "Please choose your website font color "
            },
            "sitefont":{
                required: "Please choose your website font "
            },
            "galleryimages":{
                required: "Please upload your gallery images "
            }
        }
    });
});
/*
//Override default validator messages
$.extend($.validator.messages, {
    required: "This field is required.",
    remote: "Please fix this field.",
    email: "Please enter a fucking valid email address.",
    url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
    date: "Please enter a valid date.",
    dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
    number: "Please enter a valid number.",
    digits: "Please enter only digits.",
    creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
    equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
    accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),
    rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
    range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
    max: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
    min: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
});
*/
```

HTML:

```
            <form id="ampform" class="form form-full" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="section active" id="section1">
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="site">New AMP ⚡ Website Name</label>
                            <input id="site" name="site" type="text" placeholder="rickandmorty"/>
                            <span class="titties anim-lower">.titties.com</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="personalsiteurl">Personal Website</label>
                            <input id="personalsiteurl" name="personalsiteurl" type="text" placeholder="http://www.mywebsite.com"/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="blogurl">Blog</label>
                            <input id="blogurl" name="blogurl" type="text" placeholder="http://blog.mywebsite.com"/>
                            </li>
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="section2">
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="name">Full Name</label>
                            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Meow Meowington"/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
                            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="trump@ilovedix.com"/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="password">Password</label>
                            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="********************"/>
                            </li>
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="section3">
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="headerimage">Upload Header Image</label>
                            <input id="headerimage" name="headerimage" type="text" placeholder="Upload Header Image"/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="header1">Primary Header Text</label>
                            <input id="header1" name="header1" type="text" placeholder="My Amazing Website"/>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="header2">Secondary Header Text</label>
                            <input id="header2" name="header2" type="text" placeholder="Photography Pro"/>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="headerfont">Choose a Header Font</label>
                            <input id="headerfont" name="headerfont" type="text" placeholder="Fontly"/>
                            </li>
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="section4">
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="menucolor">Pick a Menu Background Color</label>
                            <input id="menucolor" name="menucolor" type="text" placeholder="As Black as my Soul"/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="menufontcolor">Pick a Menu Font Color</label>
                            <input id="menufontcolor" name="menufontcolor" type="text" placeholder="As Red as your Blood"/>
                            </li>
                        <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="menufont">Pick a Menu Font</label>
                            <input id="menufont" name="menufont" type="text" placeholder="As Green as Envy"/>
                            </li>
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="section5">
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="backgroundcolor">Pick a Website Background Color</label>
                            <input id="backgroundcolor" name="backgroundcolor" type="text" placeholder="As Blue as Your Balls"/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="sitefontcolor">Pick a Website Font Color</label>
                            <input id="sitefontcolor" name="sitefontcolor" type="text" placeholder="As Orange as Trump"/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="sitefont">Pick a Website Font</label>
                            <input id="sitefont" name="sitefont" type="text" placeholder="As Dark as my Humor"/>
                            </li>
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="section6">

                            <li>
                            <label class="field-label" for="galleryimages">Upload Gallery Images</label>
                            <input id="galleryimages" name="galleryimages" type="text" placeholder="Upload Gallery Images"/>
                            </li>
            </div>
</form>
```

How can I allow it to still validate the section even if the non required input fields are empty? So far even though I have them set to `required: false` in my validation rules with `url: true` it still will not allow me to move forward unless I fill all of the fields first so they're "valid"

Basically, I still want it to allow the input to validate and let you pass on to the next section if you leave an empty field but if you do decide to fill it out it will make sure it's a valid URL

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

```
function isSectionValid(){
    var $section = $('.section.active').find('input');
    var allValid = true;
    if($section.valid()){
        return allValid;
    };
};
```

In your code, `$section` represents a collection of jQuery objects, which is attached to the `.valid()` method.  However, you cannot attach more than one object to the jQuery Validate methods (*only the first matching element is used*).

**Good**:

```
$('#myElement').valid();   // single matching element
```

**No Good**:

```
$('.myElements').valid();  // collection of matching elements
```

The workaround is to use a jQuery `.each()`:

```
$('.myElements').each(function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

Try something like this:

```
function isSectionValid(){
    var allValid = true;
    $('.section.active input').each(function() {
        if (! $(this).valid()) {
            allValid = false;
        }
    });
    return allValid;
};
```

The `allValid` variable starts out `true`.  If any single `input` element within `.section.active` evaluates as **not** valid, then `allValid` is set to `false`.  After all fields are checked, `allValid` is returned.

Comment: i tried with this method but still get the same error, it seems that if I set it to set 'url: false' or just don't require validation at all on those it works just fine, maybe 'url: true' somehow make the element still required if used.. perhaps I should validate the URL with a regex method instead for those two inputs? Do you have any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: @user1427307, none of the built-in methods require that a field be filled out except for the `required` rule.  However, if you wrote the `url` method yourself, it's very possible you've made it also required.

Comment: didn't write any special url method, just using jquery validate, i was able to fix my issue, added the answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a work around solution by using the :not selector and adding an ignore class to both the inputs I wanted my code to ignore and adjusting my validation code in the following way:

```
function isSectionValid(){
    var $section = $('.section.active').find('input:not(".ignore")');
    var allValid = true;
    if($section.valid()){
        return allValid;
    };
};
```

then I just added the ignore class to the inputs it should "ignore" validation for:

```
<li>
<label class="field-label" for="personalsiteurl">Personal Website</label>
<input class="ignore" id="personalsiteurl" name="personalsiteurl" type="text" placeholder="http://www.mywebsite.com"/>
</li>
<li>
<label class="field-label" for="blogurl">Blog</label>
<input class="ignore" id="blogurl" name="blogurl" type="text" placeholder="http://blog.mywebsite.com"/>
</li>
```